# How to write a function that generates ID by taking missing items in a sequence?

Tags: c#

How can I write an algorithm that can take unused ID's out of a sequence starting from 1 to 99 in the format "C00"? For example `NewId(['C01', 'C02', 'C03'])` should emit 'C04', but `NewId(['C02', 'C03', 'C04'])` should emit C01, and `NewId(['C01', 'C03', 'C04'])` should result in C02.

I wrote an implementation but the result is wrong.

Example : CAT_ID : C01, C02, C05, C06, C11. When I run it, the expected result is C03. My algorithm is as follows:

1. Sort ID asc
2. Go through every item in the list
3. Compare first value with the next, if they are not the same, add 1 and exit loop.

This is my code:

```
 public static string Get_AreaID_Auto()
 {
    string result = "";
    if (db.TESTs.ToList().Count <= 0)
    {
        result = "01";
    }
    else
    {
        int maxId = 0;
        foreach (var item in db.TESTs.OrderBy(e => e.CAT_ID).ToList())
        {
            if (int.Parse(item.CAT_ID.Substring(1)) + 1 != int.Parse(item.CAT_ID.Substring(1)))
            {
                maxId = int.Parse(item.CAT_ID.Substring(1) + 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (maxId.ToString().Length)
        {
            case 1:
                if (maxId == 9)
                {
                    result = "10";
                }
                else
                    result = "0" + (maxId + 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "" + (maxId + 1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return "C" + result;
}
```

Can someone point out what is wrong?

Comment: Why not make use of the Databases `Auto Increment` functionality and save yourself a lot of heart ache

Comment: Auto increment in database not logic. Example : you have 1,2,3,4,5 . If you delete 2,3 , the Id next will 6 , not logic.

Comment: What do you mean not logic, if those are deleted you want the new id to be 2 as 2,3 where deleted

Comment: I think you not understand .I want a function create ID . Normal , i create ID as C01,C02,C03,C04,C05,C06,C07 (I have 7 row in database) . I'll delete C03 and C04 , database have 5 row , when i create new row, the ID will C03 . Please read algorithm clearly.Thank guys

Comment: The problem in here i need compare two value side by side. C01,C02,C05,C06,C11 such as 1+1 =2 (ok) , 2+1 # 5 then value =2

Comment: You want to find a missing element in the sequence? e.g. `1, 2, 3, 5, 6 => 4;  2, 3, 4, 5, 6 => 1; 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => 6`

Comment: Yes, exactly as GeirGrusom say that  , Three case in here . I try it, can you help me ?

Comment: In the future start out by [telling people what you want to achieve](http://xyproblem.info/) rather than only stating that your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
public static string Get_AreaID_Auto()
{
    var existing = db.TESTs.Select(e => e.CAT_ID).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    if (existing.Count == 0)
    {
        return "C01";
    }
    else
    {
        return
            existing
                .Concat(new [] { "" })
                .Select((x, n) => new
                {
                    actual = x,
                    expected = String.Format("C{0:00}", n + 1),
                })
                .Where(x => x.actual != x.expected)
                .Select(x => x.expected)
                .First(); 
    }
}
```

This uses a generate and test approach. No parsing necessary.

I just realised with the `.Concat(new [] { "" })` change that the `if` statement is now no longer required. You can do this instead:

```
public static string Get_AreaID_Auto()
{
    return
        db.TESTs
            .Select(e => e.CAT_ID)
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToArray()
            .Concat(new [] { "" })
            .Select((x, n) => new
            {
                actual = x,
                expected = String.Format("C{0:00}", n + 1),
            })
            .Where(x => x.actual != x.expected)
            .Select(x => x.expected)
            .First();
}
```

Comment: ok , you right , it's work , no parsing . When i use code with GeirGrusom , I miss trouble `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Comment: Hi enigmativity , In here , you forget `09` and next is `10` , it'get error `Sequence contains no elements` ,

Comment: @BrianCrist - I fixed it. The problem was when the two sequences were identical it failed. I fixed that with `.Concat(new [] { "" })`.

Comment: @BrianCrist - I've just made a change. I realised that the `if` statement is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static string Get_AreaID_Auto()
{
    string result = "";
    if (db.TESTs.ToList().Count <= 0)
    {
        result = "01";
    }
    else
    {
    var item = db.TESTs.OrderByDescending(e => e.CAT_ID).First();
    result = int.Parse(item.CAT_ID.Substring(1)) + 1;    
    }
    return string.Format("C{0:D3}",result);
}
```

Updated Code...Now Try this

```
public static string Get_AreaID_Auto()
{
    string result = "";
    if (db.TESTs.ToList().Count <= 0)
    {
        result = "01";
    }
    else
    {
var items = db.TESTs.OrderBy(e => e.CAT_ID).ToArray();
for(int i=0;i<items.count;i++)
{   
    if ((i==items.count-1) || (int.Parse(items[i].CAT_ID.Substring(1)) + 1 != int.Parse(items[i+1].CAT_ID.Substring(1))))
            {
                result = int.Parse(items[i].CAT_ID.Substring(1) + 1);
                break;
            }   
}    
    }
    return string.Format("C{0:D2}",result);
}
```

Comment: Well, better approach would be to use database auto increment functionality but assuming you are trying to do this in code for a reason.

Comment: It's not work.In here , i don't want use identity auto increment of database, it no logicaly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution I think would work:

```
var items = db.TESTs.Select(x => int.Parse(x.CAT_ID.Substring(1))).OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();

if(!items.Any())
    return "C01";

int current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if (items[i] > current + 1)
            return "C" + (current + 1) .ToString("00");
    current = items[i];
}

return "C" + (items.Max() + 1).ToString("00");
```

Comment: No problem , please read s issue a clearly , and then give me some advice code.thank guys

Comment: Try with 3 case :`1, 2, 3, 5, 6 => 4;    2, 3, 4, 5, 6 => 1;   1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => 6`  . Not working

Comment: This code returns C04, C01 and C06 in my tests. Maybe you missed my edit? I had forgotten `.ToString("00")` on the last case.

Comment: I'm so sory , when i try it , i get trouble `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`   at line  `var items = db.TESTs.Select(x => int.Parse(x.CAT_ID.Substring(1))).OrderBy(v => v).ToArray();`

Comment: The issue is that you are using EntityFramework, and EnityFramewok cannot do a Parse. You need to enumerate the list first, and then parse them. So just switch it around.

`db.TESTs.Select(x => x.CAT_ID).ToArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Substring(1))).OrderBy(v => v).ToArray()`